# CSS Adjusting a video's height from the bottom without adjusting the video position

Tags: css, html, video

I have this HTML code:

```
<div style="width:100vw;height:100vw;position:fixed">
  <video autoplay loop>
    <source src="videos/test.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
</div>
```

It shows the `video` fine. Now what I need to do is cut the video's `height` to any `%` without changing the original size of the `video`.

For example this is what it looks currently

[image: SS]

Now I need to change some CSS so now the `video` shows only THIS PART IN RED:

[image: SS2]

If I make the `height` to say `50%` of the `video` element it changes the size of the `video` as well which is not what I want to achieve.

Also my aim is to change this property dynamic so I can't create two `div`s or something like that.

Any solutions?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution:
https://jsfiddle.net/2kv6Ldom/1/

```
    <div class="container">
        <div class="videoWrapper">
            <video autoplay src="http://html5demos.com/assets/dizzy.mp4"></video>
        </div>
    </div>

.container {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
}

.videoWrapper {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 50vh;
    overflow: hidden;
}

video {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `padding-bottom` to "fake" the `height` making it responsive

```css
body {
  margin: 0
}
.container {
  position: relative;
  /* 16/9 AR */
  padding-bottom: 56.25%;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-width: 100%;
}
.container iframe {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/QILiHiTD3uc" frameborder='0' allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: When I resize my browser using this solution, it goes weird. I won't be able to use % but a fixed padding bottom.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/bj5igz this is how it looks when the browser is resized this much. Now this is how it looks when the browser is resized to a different resolution: http://prntscr.com/bj5ke2. The padding-bottom is 50%. Is there a way to tackle this?

Comment: you have to use the `padding-bottom` value according to the AR (aspect ratio) of your video., if is 16:9 then set 56.25% if not you can calculate like this: `B / (A / 100) = C%` So for 16:9 (where 16 is A and 9 is B): `9 / .16 = 56.25 (%)`

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the CSS property **object-fit: cover**

Then set the wrapper container to the desired size.